# What does the compiler optimization "constant propagation" mean?

Tags: c++, templates, code-size

From Effective C++ by Scott Meyers:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix: private SquareMatrixBase<T> {

public:

    SquareMatrix( ) 
     : SquareMatrixBase<T>(n, 0), 
       pData(new T[n*n]) 
    {
         this->setDataPtr(pData.get()); 
    } 

        ...
private:

    boost::scoped_array<T> pData;
};
```

> Regardless of where the data is
>   stored, the key result from a bloat
>   point of view is that now many — maybe
>   all — of SquareMatrix’s member
>   functions can be simple inline calls
>   to base class versions that are shared
>   with all other matrices holding the
>   same type of data, regardless of their
>   size. At the same time, SquareMatrix
>   objects of different sizes are
>   distinct types, so even though, e.g.,
>   SquareMatrix<double, 5> and
>   SquareMatrix<double, 1 0> objects use
>   the same member functions in
>   SquareMatrixBase<double>, there’s no
>   chance of passing a
>   SquareMatrix<double, 5> object to a
>   function expecting a
>   SquareMatrix<double, 1 0>. Nice, no?
>
> Nice, yes, but not free. The versions
>   of invert with the matrix sizes 
>   hardwired into them are likely to
>   generate better code than the shared
>   version where the size is passed as a
>   function parameter or is stored in the
>   object. For example, in the
>   size-specific versions, the sizes
>   would be compile-time constants, hence
>   eligible for such optimizations as
>   constant propagation, including their
>   being folded into the generated
>   instructions as immediate operands.
>   That can’t be done in the
>   size-independent version.

In above description in last paragraph it was mentioned as "hence eligible for such optimizations as constant propagation, including their being folded into the
generated instructions as immediate operands". What does this statment mean? Kindly request to explain this.

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_propagation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constant Propagation is a very simple (in the principle) optimization left to compilers.

```
size_t radius = 5;
size_t diameter = 2*radius;
float perimeter = diameter * 3.1416f;
```

This will be reduce by the compiler by propagating the constants:

- notice that the value of `radius` is known
- execute the computation of `2*radius` (this is constant folding)
- the value of `diameter` is therefore known
- execute the computation of `diameter * 3.1416f`
- the value of `perimeter` is therefore known

The program is thus equivalent to:

```
size_t radius = 5;
size_t diameter = 10;
float perimeter = 31.416f;
```

Note that there are many other forms of optimization, for example, if `radius` and `diameter` are now no longer needed, we could remove them and only keep the `perimeter`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have original code like:

```
a:=3;
b:=4;
b+=1;
b+=2;
a:=a+b;
```

then the statements can be optimized by the compilers as:

```
b==7;
a==10;
```

That's called constant propagation and constant folding.